# Umlauts in htaccess redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

The following htaccess rule doesn't work because of the umlauts.

```
Redirect 301 /xyz/händedruck.html  /new/händedruck.html
```

How can this redirect be modified so that it works?

Comment: In which encoding did you save your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try encoded URL instead: `/xyz/h%C3%A4ndedruck.html`

To get this string in PHP you can use the `urlencode` function.

There are also many websites that can do urlencoding for you. For example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: You might should add some little information how you turned `ä` into `%C3%A4`.

Comment: A link might be helpful here too.

Comment: but there is also one more problem: now he redirects to the right url but he doesn't detect a url with umlauts.
for example:
when I go to the url http://test.com/händedruck.html he doesn't detect the following rule:
Redirect 301 /h%C3%A4ndedrick.html  /new/h%C3%A4ndedruck.html